# Add blending javascript function to make content fade into another content inside a column / making this work for two separate columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**javascript blending function** ----->  **one content (text,images) inside a column fades into a second content by pressing a square button (either 1 or 2)** with also with the option to go back to the first content again.

Full code of the function with animation of the fade effect on one column with two contents can be found here:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Y7sd/3/)

Now adding this on 4 columns :
**result ----> all the 4 columns got distorted, all on one line vertically and the function distorting the column's size.**

Code with the 4 columns , as a disaster once the function is added with it's div. **NOTE: I used toogle css/html structure for the 4 columns as it's the best layout.In case you're wondering.**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HD8W5/)

- How can I **add this function correctly on column 1 and 4** (total
    of 2 columns with this effect)

  - Using two columns with this function, will it need a 
    **multifunction script**? `what needs to be added make both work?` 
    (don't know much on javascript, iam afraid)

****The original structure of the columns that supposed to be 2 columns on each row.**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GakT/)

****Cannot put all the codes here because there is not enough space to post it here, just mentioning it, have knowledge that most of the time it has to be added.****

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181721 - to elaborate, you're page's images are not hosted on Google's servers permanently for searching and as long as you deny access to them from the outside (like robots.txt or even using login authentication) they'll disappear from the results

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: This isn't a SEO question this is a jquery question.. look at both those JSFiddle's

Comment: Okay it seems you edited a old question from a different question into a new question yeah.. that won't work. You have to somehow make a new question. Try making a new account and re-posting it, I guess.. Seems more like a HTML question then a Javascript one.. if it looks bad on the page then the HTML is wrong. Try using tool like Dreamweaver for HTML editing. I can't seem to understand do you want them to be on 1 row like across 4 different article box's or 4 article box's going downwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
Try this out [The JQuery Fixed JSFiddle and new HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/2Y7sd/8/)

Fixed the HTML glitch [Fixed HTML AND CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/qLTMf/1734/)
Newest HTML looks like this

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="outer" class="cf">
        <!-- first -->
        <div class="holder f_left">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="column_title">
                    2014
                </div>
                <h4>GOLD</h4>
                <hr>
                <div class="entry-content" id="box1_c1">
                    <div class="post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized entry">
                        <div class="shadow">
                            <img src="images/ody.png" width="140" height="147" alt="img" class="img_right f_right">
                            <p>Universe itself is infinite erj rjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj
                                rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjsw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash
                                hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu</p>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c1">1</div>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c2">2</div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- end of shadow -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of post -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of entry-content box1_c1 -->

                <div class="entry-content" id="box1_c2" style="display: none">
                    <div class="post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized entry">
                        <div class="shadow">
                            <img src="images/ody.png" width="140" height="147" alt="img" class="img_right f_left">
                            <p>SECOND SIDE erj rjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi
                                rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjsw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu</p>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c1">1</div>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c2">2</div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- end of shadow -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of post -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of entry-content box1_c2 -->
            </div>
            <!--  end of column -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of holder -->

        <!-- second -->
        <div class="holder f_left">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="column_title">
                    2014
                </div>
                <h4>PEARL</h4>
                <hr>
                <div class="entry-content" id="box2_c1">
                    <div class="post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized entry">
                        <div class="shadow">
                            <img src="images/ody.png" width="140" height="147" alt="img" class="img_right f_right">
                            <p>Universe itself is infinite erj rjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj
                                rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjsw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash
                                hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu</p>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c1">1</div>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c2">2</div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- end of shadow -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of post -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of entry-content box2_c1 -->

                <div class="entry-content" id="box2_c2" style="display: none">
                    <div class="post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized entry">
                        <div class="shadow">
                            <img src="images/ody.png" width="140" height="147" alt="img" class="img_right f_left">
                            <p>SECOND SIDE erj rjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi
                                rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjsw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu</p>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c1">1</div>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c2">2</div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- end of shadow -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of post -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of entry-content box2_c2 -->
            </div>
            <!-- end of column -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of holder -->

        <!-- third -->
        <div class="holder f_left">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="column_title">
                    2013
                </div>
                <h4>ROSE</h4>
                <hr>
                <div class="entry-content" id="box3_c1">
                    <div class="post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized entry">
                        <div class="shadow">
                            <img src="images/ody.png" width="140" height="147" alt="img" class="img_right f_right">
                            <p>Universe itself is infinite erj rjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj
                                rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjsw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash
                                hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu</p>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c1">1</div>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c2">2</div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- end of shadow -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of post -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of entry-content box3_c1 -->

                <div class="entry-content" id="box3_c2" style="display: none">
                    <div class="post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized entry">
                        <div class="shadow">
                            <img src="images/ody.png" width="140" height="147" alt="img" class="img_right f_left">
                            <p>SECOND SIDE erj rjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi
                                rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjsw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu</p>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c1">1</div>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c2">2</div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- end of shadow -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of post -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of entry-content box3_c2 -->
            </div>
            <!--  end of column -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of holder -->

        <!-- fourth -->
        <div class="holder f_left">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="column_title">
                    Sep 2013
                </div>
                <h4>LIME</h4>
                <hr>
                <div class="entry-content" id="box4_c1">
                    <div class="post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized entry">
                        <div class="shadow">
                            <img src="images/ody.png" width="140" height="147" alt="img" class="img_right f_right">
                            <p>Universe itself is infinite erj rjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj
                                rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjsw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash
                                hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu</p>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c1">1</div>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c2">2</div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- end of shadow -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of post -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of entry-content box4_c1 -->

                <div class="entry-content" id="box4_c2" style="display: none">
                    <div class="post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized entry">
                        <div class="shadow">
                            <img src="images/ody.png" width="140" height="147" alt="img" class="img_right f_left">
                            <p>SECOND SIDE erj rjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi
                                rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjsw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu</p>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c1">1</div>
                            <div class="square" contentId="c2">2</div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- end of shadow -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of post -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of entry-content box4_c2 -->
            </div>
            <!-- end of column -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of holder -->

    </div>
    <!-- end of outer -->
</div>
<!-- end of wrapper -->
```

JQuery Looks like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".square", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("contentId");
    var box_name_full = $(this).closest('div.entry-content').attr('id');
    var box_split = $(this).closest('div.entry-content').attr('id').split("_");
    var box_name = box_split[0];
    var box_c = box_split[1];

    //alert("box_name_full = " + box_name_full);
    //alert("box_name = " + box_name);
    //alert("box_c = " + box_c);

    if ($("#" + box_name + "_" + id).is(":visible"))
        $("#" + box_name + "_" + id).fadeOut("slow").hide();


    if (id == "c1") {
        //Make the first square box red color
        $("div[id^='" + box_name + "'] div.square[contentId='c1']").css('background', 'red');
        //Make the second square box gray color
        $("div[id^='" + box_name + "'] div.square[contentId='c2']").css('background', '#CCC');

        if ($("#" + box_name + "_" + "c2").is(":visible")) {
            $("#" + box_name + "_" + "c2").fadeOut("slow").hide();
        }
        $("#" + box_name + "_" + id).fadeIn('slow').show();
    } else if (id == "c2") {
        //Make the second square box red color
        $("div[id^='" + box_name + "'] div.square[contentId='c2']").css('background', 'red');
        //Make the first square box gray color
        $("div[id^='" + box_name + "'] div.square[contentId='c1']").css('background', '#CCC');

        if ($("#" + box_name + "_" + "c1").is(":visible")) {
            $("#" + box_name + "_" + "c1").fadeOut("slow").hide();
        }
        $("#" + box_name + "_" + id).fadeIn("slow").show();
    }
});
```

I cleaned up the HTML from that [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HD8W5/)

Any time your HTML gets strange just put it into this website http://jsbeautifier.org/ and you will see any mistakes like extra `</div>`'s etc...
Before the clean up the end of wrapper ended after the first 2 article box's, now it ends all the way at the bottom of all 4 article box's. Still probably javascript errors but this is a start.

Heres the new JSFiddle with the new HTML only [New JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HD8W5/2/)

First problem you will notice when clicking both those red squares is that the second red square is almost right I guess.. but the first default one is wrong.. that's because the HTML is wrong for the first one you will see

first entry content has

```
<div class="entry-content" id="c1">
```

Has inside it a

```
<div id="details">
<div style="display">
<div class="post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized entry">
<div class="shadow">
```

4 different `<div>`'s

now the second one has

```
<div class="entry-content" style="display: none" id="c2">
```

has only

```
<div class="shadow">
```

So maybe the first only needs a `<div class="shadow">` and nothing else?
I could tell you right now that the first one doesn't need `<div style="display">` this line does nothing.

Here below is your whole HTML, I've removed the `<div style="display>` and the `</div>` from first one only

```
<body>
    <!-- onload="clickMenu('outer','div','more')" -->
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="outer" class="cf">
            <div class="column f_left">
                <!-- first -->
                <div class="holder">
                    <div class="column_box">
                        <div class="column_title">
                            2014
                        </div>
                        <h4>GOLD</h4>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="entry-content" id="c1">
                            <div id="details">
                                <div class="post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized entry">
                                    <div class="shadow">
                                        <img src="images/ody.png" width="140" height="147" alt="img" class="img_right f_right">
                                        <p>Universe itself is infinite erj rjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash
                                            hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjsw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj</p>
                                        <div class="square" contentId="c1">1</div>
                                        <div class="square" contentId="c2">2</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end of entry-content c1 -->
                        <div class="entry-content" style="display: none" id="c2">
                            <div class="shadow">
                                <img src="images/ody.png" width="140" height="147" alt="img" class="img_right f_left">
                                <p>SECOND SIDE erj rjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu
                                    tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjsw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu hjshj hafshfash
                                    hrhqw jrqwlrqwjrytturtu</p>

                                <div class="square" contentId="c1"></div>
                                <div class="square" contentId="c2"></div>

                            </div>
                            <!-- end of shadow -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- end of entry-content c2 -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of post (column_box) -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of holder -->
            </div>
            <!--  end of column f_left -->
        </div>
        <!--  end of outer cf -->

        <!-- second -->
        <div class="holder">
            <div class="column_box">
                <div class="column_title">
                    2014
                </div>
                <h4>PEARL</h4>
                <hr>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <div class="post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized entry">
                        <div class="shadow">
                            <img src="images/ody.png" width="140" height="147" alt="img" class="img_left f_left">
                            <p>rjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfashrjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfashrjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre
                                ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfashjrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfashjrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfashjrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi
                                rytturtu hjshj hafshfashjrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash</p>
                            <!-- this is disabled.
                                <div class="more">
                                    <i class="show">more &#187;</i>
                                    <i class="hide">&#171; less</i>
                                    <br />
                                    <img src="more/rabbit.jpg" alt="rabbit" title="">
                                    <p>So she was considering, in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.</p>
                                    <p>There was nothing so very remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself "Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be too late!" (when she thought it over afterwards it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all</p>
                                </div> <!~~ close more ~~>
 -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- end of shadow -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of post -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of entry-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- end of column_box -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of holder -->

        <div class="column f_left">
            <!-- third -->
            <div class="holder">
                <div class="column_box">
                    <div class="column_title">
                        2013
                    </div>
                    <h4>DIAMOND</h4>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <div class="post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized entry">
                            <div class="shadow">
                                <img src="images/ody.png" width="140" height="147" alt="img" class="img_right f_right">
                                <p>Universe itself is infinite erj rjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw
                                    jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwjhjsw jrqwlrqwjhjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash hrhqw jrqwlrqwj</p>
                                <!-- disabled content
                                <div class="more">
                                    <i class="show">more &#187;</i>
                                    <i class="hide">&#171; less</i>
                                    <br />
                                    <img src="more/rabbit.jpg" alt="rabbit" title="">
                                    <p>So she was considering, in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.</p>
                                    <p>There was nothing so very remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself "Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be too late!" (when she thought it over afterwards it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all</p>
                                </div> <!~~ close more ~~>
 -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- end of shadow -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- end of post -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of entry-content -->
                </div>
                <!--  end of column_box -->
            </div>
            <!-- end of holder -->

            <!-- fourth -->
            <div class="holder">
                <div class="column_box">
                    <div class="column_title">
                        Sep 2013
                    </div>
                    <h4>ROSE</h4>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <div class="post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized entry">
                            <div class="shadow">
                                <img src="images/ody.png" width="140" height="147" alt="img" class="img_left f_left">
                                <p>rjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfashrjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfashrjrw jrwjrwhwrj jarjearjar jrajrajraj
                                    ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfashjrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfashjrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfashjrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu
                                    tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfashjrajrajraj ytre ryeyrey rrturtu tyyiyiyi rytturtu hjshj hafshfash</p>
                                <!--
                                <div class="more">
                                    <i class="show">more &#187;</i>
                                    <i class="hide">&#171; less</i>
                                    <br />
                                    <img src="more/rabbit.jpg" alt="rabbit" title="">
                                    <p>So she was considering, in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.</p>
                                    <p>There was nothing so very remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself "Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be too late!" (when she thought it over afterwards it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all</p>
                                </div> <!~~ close more ~~>
 -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- end of shadow -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- end of post -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of entry-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- end of column_box -->
            </div>
            <!-- end of holder -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of column f_left -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of wrapper -->
```

Comment: Thank you so much in helping me in this, you are a miracle! :) The original layout of the columns is in this js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4DGX4/ , I'm sorry I completely forgot to post it, I guess my head is everywhere lately with home tasks :( I wish I could have posted it as a new question but not allowed.

Comment: I saw the button of the jsfiddle you made is working now, the only issue is the layout that is killing me :( honestly just want to make 4 columns looking like this recent jsfiddle i posted (I mean by the positioning of two columns on each row and the look of it) it seemed so difficult that I had to take it from an example that gave this errors in the first place.Is there an easier way to make this type of layout columns with the same look? The html code I used is more of a mess, can imagine but didnt have much option.

Comment: maybe this layout is easier http://jsfiddle.net/AXm7N/ ??? It doesn't have a holder,it's pretty basic, I was once told this was useless that is why I didn't stick to it in the first place puff but maybe it could work?

Comment: Box 1, 3, 4 work perfectly.. But 2 messes up because it's some glitch in the HTML and CSS.. I can't figure it out, I don't usually use HTML or CSS very often. What I would do to fix that bug is let it happen. Then open in Chrome `Ctrl+Shift+I` to view Developer Tools and select the HTML it generated with the bad glitch then put it into Dreamweaver or whatever HTML/CSS editor you use and try to fix it.. Then update your original HTML with the fix, if it doesn't cause any problems on default site visit then it wouldn't have any further problems.

Comment: It's amazing what you did and it's perfect,thank you so much for this, don't know how to thank you (apart from the two bounties I keep my word on rewarding you).About the 2nd column it doesn't really matter,it doesn't need it, can the column or layout be affected if I remove the function from it? Is there a way to add border on each column? It's absolutely perfect in every way, you really saved me :) , will use developer tools but on the final stage on every page made.Thank you so much again! :) You are a Genius!

Comment: Just a bit of trial and error hehe, nope the function is universal you just the entry-content called box1_c1 or box9999_c1 just make sure there is another box9999_c2 and it wont have any problem you pick any number you wish too. As for borders that CSS.. there is probably tutorials for that on google.. or u could use HTML table's they got border property on them. But it's recommended to use CSS nowdays.

Comment: hi again, iam sorry if i'm a pain, but I noticed that the function doesn't appear at all on Internet Explorer 8 is there a way to add this function for this browser? The function is there ready and all just maybe instead of text button replace it with the square button? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056113/basic-simple-modal-pop-up-div-js-script-that-appears-next-to-the-link-button

Comment: I don't understand what you mean again the red square button if you put a number between the <div whatever>right here</div> then the number will show up in the square otherwise it should just be a red or gray square.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didnt explain well, what I meant was if I look at the 4 columns with the function and the buttons on Internet Explorer 8 nothing appears, no function, no buttons, so I was thinking maybe in this case for this specific browser call another function,like the link from the previous comment I posted.Also noticed about what you meant with the column 2 making the layout extend (stretch,expand), only  when the code got transferred to the main page.

Comment: I've been looking at the web developer tools and don't see the error at all, will keep on looking though somehow looks like maybe this code is the one giving the problem as this whole structure was made for a purpose of expanding the columns,or maybe Iam wrong, dont know much.  
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
 content: " ";
 display: table;
}

Comment: ok I did something weird, i removed this <div class="post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized entry"> that was under  <div class="entry-content" id="box2_c2" style="display: none"> and the column 2 works the same as the rest of them without the <body> expanding but now appears another issue, the two columns from the bottom row are now out of the wrapper (marked in red) how can I add another wrapper,or this is out of the rules of css? this div postype is definately the obstacle ... or maybe the div has to be placed somewhere else?

Comment: Even JSFiddle doesn't work on internet explorer 8 (which is what I have with Windows XP). I wouldn't touch the `div class wrapper` it probably has to have all the `entry-content divs` inside it. The wrapper is used in your CSS to make the width of all the box's inside it 880 pixels which probably makes sure only 2 fit per page vertically. I didn't see the other stuff in your CSS there has to be things like .post {} .type-post {} .status-publish {} .format-standard {} like 8  CSS codes with brackets. Everytime you put a space in `class=""` then it's a new CSS brick of code.

Comment: what could be causing for the second column by pressing button 2 expanding the body with gaps... :( really dont understand all the other columns work perfectly, dont get it

Comment: Did you mess around with CSS checkmark clicking? see what happens like this image http://i.imgur.com/6K2IGhl.png Could you make post a link with the column 2 messing up? Is it the same link in my answer? yeah I said the box 2 messes up.. I couldn't figure it out it's most likely the box gets too big to fit on the page so it has to be bumped down to the second row.

Comment: but I made the columns width smaller down to 290px (before it was 320px) and looking at the column 2 when pressing the button 2 it doesnt look like it takes so much space.Tried the css check mark clicking nothing so far...

Comment: Try working from scratch with this basic HTML/CSS http://jsfiddle.net/qLTMf/1726/

Comment: dont know how to do it, this is something I left 4 years ago and starting from 0, will try to look further to find some way to sort out the current one.Thanks for all your help, it was very generous of you to take your time in this and I appreciate it immensely.

Comment: Here I updated the example just changing the CSS width property for left and right, it does look ugly because lots of CSS is missing you can just copy/paste that in http://jsfiddle.net/qLTMf/1732/ If you don't like the fact that the column's can spread out to become bigger if you make the page bigger you can fix their sizes by changing the parent `width: auto` to like `width: 1200px` or something like that the parent is the container for 2 columns only!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qLTMf/1734/ not much fixing to you I'm pretty sure you can fix it from here, only needs some padding and that's about it.. the bug is gone.

Comment: this is so nice of you to help me in this, I don't know what to say :) thank you eternally, the last jsfiddle is interesting, the layout itself is very different and looks so much more confortable to navigate not to mention the function is absolutely perfect! I honestly didnt expect to find such a good soul helping me through the end.

Comment: Thank you so much for everything and for all your time in this, I'll try harder to recover points, I really wish I could give you up to 10 bounties because you helped me all the way,no one did that before, though by the situation if I'm lucky enough I hope to give you at least two hopefully soon.

Comment: Getting helped to the end I know what you mean no one ever helped me that way either they help me enough :P but if I ask for more help they start ignoring me haha. Thats why I had to abandon certain projects.. especially those with lots of math involved, math to me is just multiplication addition etc.. lol nothing passed that so when I have to draw on screen like a bullet shooting at a angle i'm completely lost anything I try to make feels like a cave man trying. But yeah man anytime you need anything I got your back.

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate this a lot :) all your help is like heaven sent, but if you don't mind me saying, if there are certain projects you like to do you shouldn't abandon them, I understand that is difficult to find people to help you out it happens to me too all the time but eventually someone will come and help.What I mean is that dont think 100% of the population doesn't help and ignores as it does happen most of the time but as I can see you helped me all the way, definately there is hope for everyone.

Comment: So give your projects a chance, someone will come and help you out you'll see.Apart from this, also remember for all the good deeds you do, you will get 100 times more.

Comment: Hello, I've got some points at least I could reward you with one bounty for the moment but I dont know how, looked everywhere in google nothing. I'm sorry I didnt see the points earlier but I had to deal with a very difficult period in my life, didn't even manage to upload the site yet after months of finally finishing it. Anyway please let me know, take care