# Basic simple modal Pop up Div (js script) that appears next to the link button (text)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I went to many sites, tried all they had, from ajax to javascript, jquery and there is not
even one pop up that could be simple. Most of them have effects and screen background with a color, nothing of that please.

- need is a **simple pop up box**  that contains text and images,just next to the link text with no effects, no screen background color.
- Using  **text as a button** (for example>> "Read More"

Just to give more of an idea, you'll find an image example.

[image: http://i35.photobucket.com/albums/d152/Ladyask21/ideapopupbox_zps683a8647.png]

Here is the code of the " read more " text that is supposed to be the button.

```
<a href="#"><p style="color: #282828 ;">Read More...</p></a>
```

I would deeply appreciate if someone can help me.Please

Comment: If you don't like the plugins, than make a custom pop-up. Hidden div that shows on click...no effects and your own css...can't be more simple than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the site below

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Add this kind of code to add a click on your `Read Me...`
Add to Read Me..

```
<a href="#" id="read_more_id_goes_here"><p style="color: #282828 ;">Read More...</p></a>
```

Then somewhere in the page I'd add this right where the example code is where stylesheet code ends. (Removing the example code for opening the dialog. and replacing it with this below)

```
<script>
$( "#read_more_id_goes_here" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
</script>
```

Code for first example (seems what you need)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS `style.css` File:

```
#dialog {
    display: none;
}

.ui-dialog-title, .ui-dialog-content, .ui-widget-content {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial",  "Verdana", "sans-serif";
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

Demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Q9qt3/12/

Comment: ok now the box appears but it appears when I refresh the page automatically without having pressed anything, then when I try to press the ''read more'' link button it doesn't work.what could I've done wrong to have caused this?

Comment: remove the  `$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });` and replace with `$( "#read_more_id_goes_here" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});`

Comment: I did it but the box stops showing up and all text from the box appears below the column plus it moves the layout of the page completely. :(

Comment: @Dalia It's best to put a demo together for easier troubleshooting. I also recommend using Chrome's console: [Chrome Developer Tools Tutorial: Console](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54IgWgoFToc) This will help you locate the problem.

Comment: I located other errors that have got nothing to do with this function :( thats the thing , this function is working but it comes automatically when the page loads on the middle of the screen. It should be called only when a user clicks on the text link button " read more" not when the page loads.

Comment: Ok now it works, but there is one slighter problem, dont know what is wrong now, ok ill explain it, when the page loads the column appears with the text below (belonging to the pop box) when I click on the "read more" the box appears and text below the column disappears and shows up on to the box. I´m so sorry for being a pain in this, I just want this issue to be over soon, it´s very close to ending.

Comment: how can I hide that text (that belongs to the pop box) under the column? The function works but this is the last issue.

Comment: `#` in CSS means it's a `id=""` dialog is the name of the id so it hides that Id by default.

Comment: one thing I´m sorry again with this I will mark the answer,you have helped me a lot in every way and I really appreciate it, I just noticed that the styles.css made the entire text from my website  into a tiny text  how can i hide and leave the original size of the text? I mean by hiding in this styles.css the
    font-size: 62.5%;

Comment: well thats a body {} in CSS that would effect the whole `<body> ... </body>` of the HTML It's meant to affect the dialog text.. so I'd put all the stuff for the dialog textbox and title box only (I found these using Google Chrome (Shift+Ctrl+I)) http://jsfiddle.net/Q9qt3/12/    `.ui-dialog-title, .ui-dialog-content, .ui-widget-content {...}`

Comment: It´s ok what I did was copy the original style of the font and put it into the style.css and the size I guessed to 75% which should be 12px approx. compared another page with the original text without using this function and seems to be the same. changing the ui dialog made the text from the box smaller better putting all fonts and sizes the same.Thank you so much for all your help I truly appreciate it and sorry for being a pain in this.Thanks

Comment: No problem man anytime. Yeah you could just use `body {}` of your original HTML page to affect the dialog box by default.

Comment: When I get more points , I´ll give you a bounty, I appreciate all ur time and effort in this, just one last thing how can I change the size of the box and position it slightly a bit down? and remove the drag symbol when the mouse goes on top of the basic dialog box because I disabled the right click

Comment: Code of the dialog is made to always pop out in the middle of the website, You could change all of that even removing drag mouse cursor by removing the ability to drag it completely here is all the codes for that http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/dialog/ more information here http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Here I did a few things you can fiddle around with it. http://jsfiddle.net/Q9qt3/14/

Comment: thank you so much!! :D I owe you a bounty,I'll keep it in mind when I reach the points again.